# Full range of values on x-axis - matlab

Tags: matlab, range, histogram

I'm trying to check the **full** range of values on the **x-axis** of a histogram, especially while I expected the full range to be `[0, 255]`, when I used the following command for the histogram `[h, bins] = hist(H)`, I got the following:

```
h =

   221    20     6     4     1     1     2     0     0     1


bins =

  Columns 1 through 7

    8.2500   24.7500   41.2500   57.7500   74.2500   90.7500  107.2500

  Columns 8 through 10

  123.7500  140.2500  156.7500
```

This implies that the maximum range I got here is up to `165`.

If we look at the histogram below, we can see that `165` seems to be the maximum number of `frequency` value. How do I know the maximum value (range) of the x-axis?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need either one of these 3 options:

```
max(H)
```

Or

```
numel(unique(H))
```

or

```
numel(H)
```

I would start at the top till you find the one you need.